# Javascript Get DOM source by adding a temp iframe

Tags: javascript

I am currently getting the DOM source from a page by first adding an iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://127.0.0.1/mypage.html" id="my_iframe"></iframe>
```

And then extracting the contents with javascript:

```
var data = $("#my_iframe").contents().find("#data");
```

This works well but My question is:

Can I do the same thing but without having to have the iframe in the body before running the javascript code?

Comment: Didn't get what you want to do. Do you want this thing without iframe?

Comment: In the DOM you can target the `document`, `window`, and `body` -- all of which should be able to provide you with the content on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://127.0.0.1/mypage.html");
var jframe = $(iframe);
$(jframe).ready(function() {
    var data = jframe.contents().find("#data");
    // Do something with data
}
```

However, unless both pages are on the same domain, this is doomed to fail in production, thanks to an irritating but vital security measure called CORS. Unless the server that you are requesting the page from has their CORS header, [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin), set to allow your page to request the content from it, you cannot do this.

If CORS doesn't stop you from doing this, you can do it differently with the `XMLHttpRequest` API.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.body.innerHTML = this.responseText;
  var data = $(fragment).find("#data");
  // Do something with data
});
oReq.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/mypage.html");
oReq.send();
```